# Angular data binding - data changed in service also

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

Hope someone can help me understand this behavior in Angular.

There is a simple input bound to a component variable using ngmodel two way-data binding. When the component initializes, the data is retrieved using the dataService which returns an employee object which works fine. But the thing is when i edit the value in the input box, the component variable employee's name changes but also the data in the service as well is changed which according to me is very weird. The data returned from the service should not be affected right? Find plunker below.

Kindly refer to this plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/wjuJLo?p=preview

```
getData() {
    console.log(this.employee);
    console.log(this.service.getEmp());
  }
```

Thanks and Regards,
Ashley

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with this part of code.

```
ngOnInit() {
        this.employee = this.service.getEmp();
      }
```

In JavaScript, variables only hold a reference to the object, not the object itself. Thus `this.employee` have a reference to `this.service.getEmp();`

So whenever you change `this.employee`, it will change the value at the reference, thus the value you will get from the service will be the updated one, not the one you expected.

Inorder to clone,

Using jquery [check this answer for more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-deep-clone-an-object-in-javascript):

```
// Shallow copy
this.employee = jQuery.extend({}, this.service.getEmp());

// Deep copy
this.employee = jQuery.extend(true, {}, this.service.getEmp());
```

Or using [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign):

`this.employee = Object.assign({}, this.service.getEmp());`

Or using [Lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#clone):

```
this.employee = _.clone(this.service.getEmp());
```

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning getEmp() to this.employee means you assign `getEmp() reference to this.empoyee` so if you change anything to this.employee then that will get reflected to getEmp() too.

Here you will have to make sure that you will `make a copy of getEmp()` before assign it back to this.employee. And that will solve your issue.

**Solution code is attached below**

```
export class App implements OnInit {
  private employee: Employee = new Employee();
  constructor(private service: dataService) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.employee = Object.assign({}, this.service.getEmp());  // making copy of getEmp()
  }

  getData() {
    console.log(this.employee);
    console.log(this.service.getEmp());
  }
}
```

Cheers!

Comment: Hi. thanks for the reply. Is that the standard way to do?